# What determines a Kerbal's uniform?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've noticed that both in the mini-window in staging mode and in the Astronaught Center some Kerbals wore a different uniform. Sometimes blue, sometimes white and sometimes yellow.

[image: Different uniforms]

Are these special Kerbals? What determines the uniform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Orange Uniforms** are unique to the original three (Jebediah, Bill, Bob).
These also "respawn" (at a quicker rate than normal recruits).

**Blue Uniforms** are ground uniforms for new recruits that aren't hired yet.

**White Uniforms** are spacesuits for hired recruits.